# after changing a user password then the session got flushed

Tags: python, django, authentication

when i changed user password the user becomes anonymous means the session get flushed after.How to solve this issue. Why this happens when the password changed.
the url has given below
path('psswdReset/',psswdReset, name = 'psswd_reset')

```
def psswdReset(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_psswd = request.POST.get('new_psswd')
        psswd = request.POST.get('psswd')
        password_is_correct = check_password(psswd, request.user.password)
        if password_is_correct:            
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            user.password = make_password(new_psswd)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Password changed successfully!')
            return render(request,'User/userPsswdReset.html',{}) 
            print('anonymouse', request.user.is_anonymous)

     return render(request,'User/userPsswdReset.html',{})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom password change view use the [update_session_auth_hash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change)